# Date of Receipt or Receiving Date

Tags: word-choice

I would like to choose between these two options. In my use-case, I refer to the date/time when a specific message was received. Which one should I choose ?

1. Date of Receipt
2. Receiving Date

And why ?

Comment: A third possibility is *Date of Reception*, or *Reception Date*. Whilst those would be unusual for such as storeroom documentation etc., *reception* is perhaps more fluent in a report. "From the moment of  reception in our warehouse, the chemicals were observed to be giving off a malodorous vapour".

Comment: Both options are grammatical and understandable, so just choose one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date of receipt.

Because the second instance is a continuous tense and, presumably, once received you stop receiving it.

Comment: ps it's 'usage' not 'use-case'